# Protobuf: is it true that when an empty protobuf object is sent, it's converted to null object?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I'm a new user of protobuf.
I found out some weird behaviour.

I have two services that communicate by protobuf.
When the first service sends an empty protobuf object to the other service, the other service doesn't get an empty protobuf, but a null.

Have you experienced this? If yes, do you know how to resolve it? I want the other service to get an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf has no concept of null; it can send a zero length payload, and that *should* deserialize as an empty object (because an empty object is zero length), but it is possible that some implementation is returning null. Frankly I'd argue that is a bug in the deserializer, but a full minimal repro would help.

Comment: The "deserializer" ia a part of protobuf package. Right? It's not a different package/product.

Comment: @CrazySynthax yes, but there are multiple implementations available, even for a single language / framework (like java, for example); are you using the Google implementation, for example?